# Swift4にコンバートするとOverlapping access to~のエラーが出てしまう。

Tags: swift4

C言語ライブラリのSwiftラッパーを呼び出して動作するプログラムを動かしています。
Xcodeは9.1です。またCライブラリラッパーはSwift4.0にコンバートしてビルド済みです。
プログラム側の設定がSwift Language Versionが3.2だとエラーは出ませんが、4.0だと「Overlapping access to~」のエラーが発生してしまいます。
ソースは以下です。

```
func CallErr(_ paramStr : String, returnStr : inout String, resultStr : inout String) {
    print("CallErr")

    var ret : Int32 = 0
    var oParam : [Int32] = [Int32](repeating: -1, count: 10)
    var paramCnt = 0
    var err : Int32 = 0

    main_proc: while(true){

        // preset
        returnStr = ""
        resultStr = ""
        ret = app.PRN_OK

        funcName = "getPRLibStatus"
        paramCnt = 3
        for i in 0..<paramCnt {
            oParam[i] = -1
        }
        ret = app.LIB.getPRLibStatus(state: &oParam[0], total: &oParam[1], fin: &oParam[2])　　　//←ここの&oParam[0]がエラー
        if (ret != app.PRN_OK) {
            resultStr = "getPRLibStatus失敗\r\n"
            err = app.LIB.getErrInfo()
            resultStr += "GetErrInfo : " + String(err) + "(" + app.ERR_MSG_MAP[err]! + ")"
            returnStr = "Call_Err : 失敗"
            break main_proc
        }
```

エラーメッセージは「Overlapping accesses to 'oParam', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable」となっています。

どのように修正すれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: OOPer様　ローカルで変数を使用することで解決できました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 4で付け加わったこちらの仕様による制限に引っかかっています。

[SE-0176 Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md)

ごくごく大雑把に説明すると、『「一つのもの」をいろんなところから同時に更新しちゃうと厄介なことが起こる場合があるから、そう言うのは禁止しちゃうよ。』(この手の意訳がお嫌いな方は原文を参照願います。)

エラーメッセージにあるようにローカル変数を使ってください。

```
    var oState: Int32 = -1
    var oTotal: Int32 = -1
    var oFin: Int32 = -1
    ret = app.LIB.getPRLibStatus(state: &oState, total: &oTotal, fin: &oFin)
    //以下本当に必要なのか不明…
    paramCnt = 3
    oParam[0] = oState
    oParam[1] = oTotal
    oParam[2] = oFin
```